# How can i convert this code snippet into LINQ format?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

```
 foreach (var invitation in PendingContactList.CollectionContent)
            {
                if (!invitation.Contact.incoming)
                {
                    contactInvitationsSent.Add(invitation);
                }
            }
```

PendingContactList is a list.

Comment: Why down vote?? Justify the reason.

Comment: Can I ask why you needed to do this?

Comment: var contactInvitationsSend = PendingContactList.CollectionContent.Where(x => !x.Contact.incoming).ToList();

Comment: This is not a code conversion service. You are supposed to give it a try, post your best try and the specific problems and *then* people will gladly help you. This includes up/downvotes that represent how well you did following the sites guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

Something like that if `contactInvitationsSent` is `List<T>`:

```
  contactInvitationsSent.AddRange(
    PendingContactList.CollectionContent.Where(item => !item.Contact.incoming)
  );
```

In case of `contactInvitationsSent` is not a `List<T>` and we don't have `AddRange` method we have to use `Add`, it seem that *Linq* is of little help in that case:

```
  foreach(var invitation in PendingContactList.CollectionContent
                     .Where(item => !item.Contact.incoming)) 
    contactInvitationsSent.Add(invitation);
```

Comment: This assumes a lot about `contactInvitationSent`. What if it was a Collection?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following, although it is not guarranteed to give you any performance boost.

```
contactInvitationSent.AddRange(PendingContactList.CollectionContent
                                                .Where(i => !i.Contact.incoming);
```

Comment: This assumes a lot about `contactInvitationSent`. What if it was a Collection?

Comment: @nvoigt - The only information we have to go on is "pendingContactList" is a list. Granted there is some guesswork here but the majority of stackoverflow questions do involve such work these days

Answer (score 0):

Just for you information, you can also install plugins like ReSharper.
And yes, the price and performance of the tool just does not always compensate for the features it provides. However, questions like thise one can be avoided :-)

There are also some free alternative available. For example the power tools.
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd

Just read more about resharper etc, goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

try something like :

```
contactInvitationsSent = PendingContactList.CollectionContent
                                    .Where(x => x.Contact.incoming == false)
                                    .Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Linq is awesome and very simple notation.

Comment: for a while you can change this line : `.Where(x => x.Contact.incoming == false)` by that `.Where(x => !x.Contact.incoming)` it will do the same

Answer (score 0):

You have to use following syntax.

`var demo = (from n in PendingContactList.CollectionContent where n.incoming==false select n).ToList();`

Comment: @Akhil Sivanandan If answer is useful, Please click on 'correct' and give 'upvote' so it will helps other to find out correct solution.